# Can I use power mock for Commercial projects?

Tags: java, powermock

Currently Mockito is being used and many bottlenecks have been encountered when testing private methods.

I want to know whether Power Mockito can be used for commercial projects/applications ?   If Power mock is used for commercial applications, what are the conditions ?

I found the License as well https://github.com/powermock/powermock/blob/master/LICENSE.txt .Franckly I am not geek at those legal terms and understanding.

Comment: `Apache License 2.0` => Yes, you can

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming but asking for legal advise.

Comment: Beyond the fact that you this is a *legal* question (and this site is about *programming* questions) - **wrong** approach. Assume that you are using some tool because **somebody** in the internet told you "this is fine". And then you get sued. And then you tell the judge "but sir, somebody in the internet told me it is fine to use this tool for my product". In that sense: if you want to receive **liable** legal advise - consider consulting an attorney specialized on such questions. And yes, that costs money. But I guess your idea is to make money with your product.

Comment: Beyond that, using PowerMock is fine. But as explained: your attitude to approach such problems - is not. Using open source for commercial products is of course possible, but you should be doing more than just putting up questions on some internet site....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IANAL but when you open that license in GitHub you see a green checkmark next to Commercial Use. It also states the license and copyright must be shipped with your software and any changes to the code (of the library itself) must be documented.

[image]